# Do we know when the first cappuccino was brewed and how it acquired its name?

Tags: cappuccino, history, coffee-culture

Is it possible to know when the first documented case of someone brewing a cappuccino coffee and how this beverage got its name?

Answer (score 3):

It was in Vienna, by a Capuchin Monk who is a friend of the owner of the first coffee shop of the city.

Please see [this previous answer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/best-stories-of-coffee-consumption-in-historical-times/2852#2852).